# How can I get the role description from the ASP.NET membership database?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, roles

How can I get the role description from the ASP.NET membership database, other than querying the database directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did look around using Reflector but didn't see any method that returns the description. The method `CreateRole()` only takes the rolename. Even the stored procedure `aspnet_Roles_GetAllRoles` only returns the name. I'm afraid you'll need to query the aspnet_Roles table directly

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478950.aspx says description is currently unused.

Answer (score 1):

To provide details, because the Description field is not natively supported, when defining roles, I supplied a custom database call taking advantage of the description field in the aspnet_Roles table created.

Specifically, I created the role using the built-in ASP.net CreateRole method

```
Roles.CreateRole("CREATED ROLE");
```

and then used direct SQL to update the ASP table using the following SQL command.

```
UPDATE dbo.aspnet_Roles SET [Description]='MY ROLE DESCRIPTION' WHERE RoleName='CREATED ROLE'
```

When I need to use the role description, I do a select

```
SELECT [Description] FROM dbo.aspnet_Roles where RoleName='CREATED ROLE'
```